# Why does endianness is a concern regarding to binary files?

Tags: endianness

I have read that endianness is a problem when talking about binary files, but I have'nt found a reason for that.

Why is that? Also why isn't it apply to text files (that are in defintion binary files that just get a different interpretation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary notation and Endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259787/binary-notation-and-endianness)

Answer (score 1):

Endianness is order within byte *subsequences*, necessarily of size over 1.

Take names, for example. In English, first names come... well, first. Then last names. For clarity, let's say that the given name precedes the family name. So "Thomas Edison, Nikola Tesla, Jack Nicholson" describes three people, whose given names are Thomas, Nikola and Jack. In Japan, family names come first, and given names follow. So e.g. "Kitano Takeshi" has Kitano as family name, and Takeshi as given name; and in English we usually write "Takeshi Kitano". Now if you aren't familiar with Japanese names or the pop culture, and you read "Shiina Ringo", you can't know if "Shiina" is a given name or a family name, unless someone informs you if "Shiina Ringo" is written in Japanese order or English order. (It's in Japanese order, "Shiina" is the family name.)

As long as you're inside the same culture, there's hardly any problem. Nobody in America would look at "Jack Frank" and doubt whether "Jack" or "Frank" was the given name. But if you go to a culture with the opposite order, suddenly a ton of problems. I live in Japan, and I have been randomly addressed as both "Mr $GivenName" and "Mr $LastName", simply because they had no idea whether I wrote my name using the Japanese or Western tradition.

On the other hand, people with mononyms don't have that problem. "Jennie" (the K-pop idol) is just "Jennie". "Cher" is just "Cher". There's no problem with "which one is the last name" when they don't use a last name.

Similarly, 16-bit integers take two bytes to represent. For example `0xDEAD` can be represented as `0xDE 0xAD` ("big endian"), or `0xAD 0xDE` ("little endian"). Conversely, if you encounter `0xDE 0xAD`, without knowing its endianness, you can't know if it's supposed to be `0xDEAD`, or `0xADDE`.

Just like with names, it usually doesn't bite you as long as you're working within the same system. Almost everything on a Windows 10 machine is little-endian. Working on a big-endian system (if you can find one, they're kind of extinct by now) will also not make problems. But if you make a little-endian file on Windows 10 and put it without change on a big-endian system without compensating for it, you'll get garbage.

Why doesn't it apply to text files? Just like why no-one messes up "Cher": when you have a stream of single bytes like e.g. `0x40`, it's `0x40` whether you write it first-byte-first, or first-byte-last. (Also, note that this is only true for text files in single-byte encodings, like ASCII, Latin-1 etc. Text files with multibyte encodings like UTF-8, UCS-2, Shift-JIS, Big5 etc are all affected by endianness.)